# Calling an action in uiviewcontroller inside another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

My app has a simple structure:

There is a ViewConroller1 which is a root view controller;

ViewController1 has a scrollview with 10 instances of another view controller, ViewController2.

There is a xib in ViewController2 and on that xib there is a UIButton. UIButton has an action in ViewController2 .m file - it is supposed to be fired whenever it is tapped.

When I run the app, i touch the button and it closes with an exception.
When I make ViewController2 the root view controller, everything runs like it supposed to.

How do I make it run correctly with ViewConroller1 being the root view controller?

Some code:

ViewController1 (GSMainVC.m)

```
#import "GSMainVC.h"
#import "GSViewController.h"

@interface GSMainVC ()

@end

@implementation GSMainVC

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    int n=10;
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width*n, self.view.frame.size.height);

    for (int i = 0; i <n; i++){
        GSViewController *gsVC = [[GSViewController alloc] init];
        CGRect cellFrame = CGRectMake(gsVC.view.frame.size.width*i, 0, gsVC.view.frame.size.width, gsVC.view.frame.size.height);
        gsVC.view.frame = cellFrame;
        [scrollView addSubview:gsVC.view];
    }

    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
}
@end
```

ViewController2 .h (GSViewController.h)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GSViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger number;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *subtitleLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *daysPlayedLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *repeatButton;

- (IBAction)toggleRepeat:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewConroller2 .m (GSViewController.m)

```
#import "GSViewController.h"

@implementation GSViewController
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;

}

- (IBAction)toggleRepeat:(id)sender {
    NSLog (@"hello");

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];        
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
@end
```

Comment: What kind of an exception are you getting?

Comment: Are you adding these 10 instances as child view controllers? If not, you should be. A more general question, is why do you need these 10 view controllers as opposed to using 10 views?

Comment: See http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: Nothing particular about the exception. Generally speaking, something goes wrong when action is handled in a child view controller. I must be forgetting something very basic here - e.g. I missed some delegation that was supposed to be there... Any ideas what common newbie mistake it could be?

Comment: Exc Bad Access is the error I'm getting

Comment: Please show your implementation, in particular how you add those sub views. One possibility is that while you add te views of your child controllers you do not retain those controllers and your buttons are then attempting to message reallocate objects. In general this sort of view controller beating is usually the wrong approach: every view does not need its own controller.

Comment: Without some code we really can't say much here, would you mind showing your implementation of VC1 and VC2? and the IBAction method related to the button?

Comment: Added some code for clarifications.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to replicate the functionality of a table view by hand. Why not just use an instance of `UITableView`?

Comment: It's not really a table, but a set of horizontally-scrolling screens. Is it still something done through `UITableView`?

Comment: You could use a `UICollectionView` or dynamically fill a `UIScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

As Johan mentioned:

> One possibility is that while you add te views of your child controllers you do not retain those controllers and your buttons are then attempting to message reallocate objects. In general this sort of view controller beating is usually the wrong approach: every view does not need its own controller.

As other people mentioned, it looks like inventing bicycle, especially when tools `UICollectionView` are available. This is the way I'm going to dig now.